# unexpected token reactjs app on codesandbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting `unexpected token on line 5` error on reactjs project when running it through codesandbox. The app works without an error when I run it on my local computer.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Header from '../Header/Header';
import Footer from '../Footer/Footer';

const App = ({ children }) => (
  <>
    <Header />

    <main>
      {children}
    </main>

    <Footer />
  </>
);

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Any suggestion why im getting that error

**UPDATE**

[Here](http://here%20is%20the%20link%20to%20codesandbox%20that%20im%20having%20issue%20with%20codesandbox.io/s/13m1wyz3pq) is the link to codesandbox

Comment: try changing <> to <div> and close it accordingly.

Comment: Line 5 is an empty line in your example. You probably need to set an option to use a Babel transpiler

Comment: Testing your code without any imports works fine on my side: https://codesandbox.io/s/033lqz24kv - so probably just a React version problem?

Comment: @lumio here is the link to codesandbox that im having issue with https://codesandbox.io/s/13m1wyz3pq

Answer (score 1):

React Fragments are a neat little feature that were released late last year with React `v16.2.0`.
Try with updated react version:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

as per react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax) many tools don’t support it yet so you might want to explicitly write `<React.Fragment>` until the tooling catches up.

Comment: here is the link to codesandbox that im having issue with https://codesandbox.io/s/13m1wyz3pq

Comment: once check your webpack config and server config file